# WSO2 API Manager fails to execute

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to install and run the WSO2 API Manager. However unfortunately I can't get it to run out of the box on Ubuntu 12.04.

I unzipped the installation to ~/wso2am-1.7.0/ as explained in [this demo](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Quick+Start+Guide).

Then, when I run this:

```
ubuntu@localhost:~/wso2am-1.7.0/bin$ ./wso2server.sh
```

The API manager fails to start and gives this output:

```
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /home/ubuntu/wso2am-1.7.0
[2014-07-08 08:37:58,044]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2014-07-08 08:37:58,066]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Operating System : Linux 3.2.0-54-virtual, amd64
[2014-07-08 08:37:58,067]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Home        : /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
[2014-07-08 08:37:58,067]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Version     : 1.7.0_60
[2014-07-08 08:37:58,067]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.60-b09,Oracle Corporation
[2014-07-08 08:37:58,068]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Carbon Home      : /home/ubuntu/wso2am-1.7.0
[2014-07-08 08:37:58,068]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Temp Dir    : /home/ubuntu/wso2am-1.7.0/tmp
[2014-07-08 08:37:58,068]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator User             : ubuntu, en-US, Etc/UTC
[2014-07-08 08:37:58,357]  WARN - ValidationResultPrinter RAM size (MB): 590 of the system is below the recommended minimum size :2048
[2014-07-08 08:37:58,374]  WARN - ValidationResultPrinter The default keystore (wso2carbon.jks) is currently being used. To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.
[2014-07-08 08:37:58,374]  WARN - ValidationResultPrinter Swap Memory size (MB): 0 of the system is below the recommended minimum size :2048
[2014-07-08 08:37:58,728]  INFO - AgentHolder Agent created !
[2014-07-08 08:37:58,815]  INFO - AgentDS Successfully deployed Agent Client
[2014-07-08 08:39:14,287]  INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Configured Registry in 4800ms
[2014-07-08 08:39:19,817]  INFO - RegistryCoreServiceComponent Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
[2014-07-08 08:39:29,184]  INFO - ApplicationManagementServiceComponent Identity ApplicationManagementComponent bundle is activated
[2014-07-08 08:39:59,533]  INFO - UserStoreMgtDSComponent Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
[2014-07-08 08:41:13,077]  INFO - TaglibUriRule TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
[2014-07-08 08:42:05,300]  INFO - ClusterBuilder Clustering has been disabled
[2014-07-08 08:42:06,112]  INFO - LandingPageWebappDeployer Deployed product landing page webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/home]
[2014-07-08 08:42:06,118]  INFO - UserStoreConfigurationDeployer User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
[2014-07-08 08:42:06,245]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLSender Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Sender...
[2014-07-08 08:42:06,316]  INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder HTTPS Loading Identity Keystore from : repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks
[2014-07-08 08:42:06,407]  INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder HTTPS Loading Trust Keystore from : repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks
[2014-07-08 08:42:06,678]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLSender Pass-through HTTPS Sender started...
[2014-07-08 08:42:06,678]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSender Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Sender...
[2014-07-08 08:42:06,691]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSender Pass-through HTTP Sender started...
[2014-07-08 08:42:08,172] ERROR - AxisConfiguration Error occured while notifying observer
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
    (...)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    (...)
[2014-07-08 08:42:08,215] ERROR - AbstractPersistenceManager Could not get the Service resource from file 
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
    (...)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    (...)
[2014-07-08 08:42:08,224] ERROR - DeploymentInterceptor Exception occurred while handling service update event. {super-tenant}
org.wso2.carbon.core.persistence.PersistenceException: Could not get the Service resource from file 
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.persistence.AbstractPersistenceManager.handleException(AbstractPersistenceManager.java:608)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.persistence.ServicePersistenceManager.getService(ServicePersistenceManager.java:122)
    (...)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 57 more
[2014-07-08 08:42:08,304]  INFO - DeploymentEngine org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
[2014-07-08 08:42:08,452]  INFO - TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/STRATOS_ROOT].File[/home/ubuntu/wso2am-1.7.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/STRATOS_ROOT]
[2014-07-08 08:42:08,816]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: Version {super-tenant}
[2014-07-08 08:42:08,958]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: Version.aar - file:/home/ubuntu/wso2am-1.7.0/repository/deployment/server/axis2services/Version.aar
[2014-07-08 08:42:09,043]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: Version {super-tenant}
[2014-07-08 08:42:10,646]  INFO - TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/authenticationendpoint].File[/home/ubuntu/wso2am-1.7.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/authenticationendpoint.war]
[2014-07-08 08:42:14,827]  INFO - TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/oauth2].File[/home/ubuntu/wso2am-1.7.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/oauth2.war]
[2014-07-08 08:42:15,480]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLListener Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Listener...
[2014-07-08 08:42:16,548]  INFO - PassThroughHttpListener Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Listener...
[2014-07-08 08:42:19,014]  INFO - ModuleDeployer Deploying module: addressing-1.6.1-wso2v10 - file:/home/ubuntu/wso2am-1.7.0/repository/deployment/client/modules/addressing-1.6.1-wso2v10.mar
[2014-07-08 08:42:19,746]  INFO - TCPTransportSender TCP Sender started
[2014-07-08 08:43:02,852]  WARN - DefaultSchemaGenerator We don't support method overloading. Ignoring [validateAudienceRestriction]
[2014-07-08 08:43:31,914]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt - 
[2014-07-08 08:44:14,212]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.registry.ws.api - 
[2014-07-08 08:44:15,840]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: wso2carbon-sts {super-tenant}
[2014-07-08 08:44:15,989]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.sts - 
[2014-07-08 08:44:16,589]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.tryit - 
[2014-07-08 08:44:16,890]  WARN - DefaultSchemaGenerator We don't support method overloading. Ignoring [getAttributeName]
[2014-07-08 08:44:18,913]  INFO - CarbonServerManager Repository       : /home/ubuntu/wso2am-1.7.0/repository/deployment/server/
Killed
```

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you edited any xml file in the product?

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you download a fresh API Manager setup and try to run the API manager.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue with API manager. but i was able to resolve it by restarting wso2am application